# Exit Application in Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, exit

I try to exit an application (need to know the base structure of Visual C++ program) but the code of the MSDN isn't accepted. What am I doing wrong?

```
private: System::Void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
}
 Application::Exit(); };
```

The errors are on running this code:
`error C3254: 'Program::Form1' : class contains explicit override 'Exit' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration`
`error C2838: 'Exit' : illegal qualified name in member declaration`
`error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`
`warning C4183: 'Exit': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'`

I could not find any helpful information on this, today is my first day with trying in VS 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Application::Exit(); is in the wrong line. Does the following work:

```
private: System::Void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
          Application::Exit(); }
};
```